# Make complex view "gradiently" transparent

Tags: android

How to make complex view (which has its own background, imageview and textview inside it) gradiently transparent? For example, first half of this view has normal colors, but the second one goes from normal to transparent?

I can't just background of this item transparent, because inside elements wouldn't be transparent. So I need kinda "transparent filter" for this view. Is even possible?

To be more concrete: I have a widget with listview. I need the last list item to be half-transparent. So the user could see the wallpaper through it. And this list item is complex, it has many small views in it.

Comment: you can override `dispatchDraw` of the root element and use porter duff tricks to gradually show all the elements

Comment: @pskink can you provide more specific information about this porter duff stuff, because it's unclear for now how to use it.

Comment: here you can find the best info on this topic: http://ssp.impulsetrain.com/porterduff.html

Comment: this is where you can start from: http://codeshare.io/ZQHcj

Comment: @pskink I guess, I do. Need to dig into it anyway. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Use `RelativeLayout`

The complex setup:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/number_picker_row_height"
    android:background="@android:color/white">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient_bg"/>
    <View
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@drawable/image" />     
</RelativeLayout>
```

in gradient_bg:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#55ffffff"
        android:centerColor="#00ffffff"
        android:endColor="#ffffffff"
        android:angle="0"
        android:dither="true"
        />
</shape>
```

This will achieve an gradient effect on top of whatever TextView, and you can also set whatever background on the RelativeLayout and also add any image view on top of the gradient background.

Hope it helps!

Comment: See my updated question. I think you misunderstood me.

Comment: after your last updates, it's now more clear, my answer doesn't apply then