# Apply alpha gradient to whole ViewGroup

Tags: android, gradient, alpha

im trying to make a gradient alpha over a ViewGroup.

I know i can use GradientDrawable but that will apply only to background.

I need the alpha to be applied to the whole view, including subviews.

Just like setting the alpha to the viewGroup as i can do with:

```
_relativeLayout.setAlpha(1);
```

If i set a background gradient alpha it doesnt apply to it subviews.

how can i get the same effect but with a gradient?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: override `dispatchDraw` or `draw` methods of your custom `ViewGroup`

Comment: And what should i do there? will it apply the alpha to its subviews too?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31135714/make-complex-view-gradiently-transparent, i sent some code to codeshare.io but it seems it is down now (http://codeshare.io/ZQHcj) or maybe it is dead forever, i domt know

Comment: i could of course to write it again but you know i am too lazy sometimes... maybe you could ask original poster of that question (Ov3r1oad) if he still has that code...

Comment: Your code should be at the answer of that question (still unanswered) if its really working.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement a simple DFS algorithm to do it

```
void setAlphaTransitively(View view, float alpha) {
    if (view == null) {
        return;
    }

    view.setAlpha(alpha);
    if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
        ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) view;
        for (int index = 0; index < viewGroup.getChildCount(); index++) {
            View child = viewGroup.getChildAt(index);
            setAlphaTransitively(child, alpha);
        }
    }
}
```